# how to change the view to horizontal in iphone application

Tags: iphone

How do I change the view to be horizontal. I do not want it to switch when the iphone is turned on its side, I want it to be permanently horizontal. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600284/iphone-sdk-locking-the-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: There are several "landscape" related questions/answers already on stackoverflow ([query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=setStatusBarOrientation)). But to answer your question directly, here's a high level summary of Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18) for this this topic:

1. Add UIInterfaceOrientation to Info.plist with string value UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight (or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft). Another option that accomplishes the same thing is to call UIApplication's setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method at startup (i.e., within applicationDidFinishLaunching:).
2. In your root view controller implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: as follows:

   ```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
      return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
   }
   ```